# Loading script with promises , jQuery isn't loading

Tags: jquery

What am I doing wrong ?

the files gets loaded, but i'm getting a 'TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function'

is my first attempt with promises.

And maybe there is a better way to do that

```
if (datePicker.type === "text") {
        jqui = true;

        function loadScript(url ,ext) {
          return new Promise(function(resolve , reject) {
            
            if(ext == 'js'){
              let script = document.createElement("script");
              script.type = 'text/javascript'
              script.src = url;
              script.onload = resolve;
              script.onerror = reject;
              document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

            }else if(ext =='css'){
              let script = document.createElement("link");
              script.href = url
              script.onload = resolve;
              script.onerror = reject;
              script.rel = 'stylesheet';
              document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

            }

          });
        }

        loadScript("https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js",'js').then(
          loadScript("https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js",'js').then(
            loadScript("https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css",'css').then(function() {

              if(window.jQuery) {
                $(".datepicker-btn").datepicker({
                  altField: ".converteddate",
                  altFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                });

                $(".datepicker-btn").on("change", setDeliverSlots);
        }else{
                console.log('jquery error');
        }
          }, function() {
            }), function() {
            }), function() {   
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

so I couldn't make it work with promises so I solved in a different way

```
        const jq = document.createElement('script')
        jq.src = 'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.5.1.min.js';
        const jui = document.createElement('script')
        jui.src = 'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js';
        const css = document.createElement('link')
        css.href = 'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css';
        css.type = 'text/css';
        css.rel = "stylesheet";
        const head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        
        head.appendChild(jq);
        jq.addEventListener('load',function(){
          console.log('jq laoded');
          head.appendChild(jui);
          jui.addEventListener('load',function(){
            console.log('jui loaded');
            head.appendChild(css)
            css.addEventListener('load',function(){
              console.log('css loaded');

              if(window.jQuery){
                $(".datepicker-btn").datepicker({altField: ".converteddate",altFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});

                $(".datepicker-btn").on("change", setDeliverSlots);

                console.log('loaded');
              }else{
                console.log('jq error');
              }

            })
          })
        })
      }
```